# Reference images for complex shapes?

Tags: print-design

What do professional artists do when preparing blueprints/reference images for vehicles like this [image: this] with complex shapes as you can see on its side. I am asking since I have seen a lot use orthographical front-,side., and top-views, but I cannot see how these views used as blueprints would feature such complex shapes.

Comment: Well if you have 2 way curvatures they can not but in fact apart of the hood details this particular car can be done with just 3 views

Comment: But they must be doing something to make blueprints of these complex shapes before trying to draw them in perspective..

Comment: I dont think they do. The bleprints are drafting tools, and composing them is pretty straightfoward. When you see an artist using the 3 views they are trying to copy an existing vehicle, which allready have the technical drawings done. The original drawer would have allready done this in reverse. But if you would design a car you wouldnt do it that way. You would just block it ut and draw it directly with perspective symmetry. Its not actually hard its just that your missing way too many of the basic toolset to actually be explained how to do it effectively. One would habe to start simple.

Answer (score 1):

About 90 years ago car stylists started to make 3D clay models of the cars. They used some special wax which was suitable for full size models.

The method is still in use. Designing is team work. Everyone in the team has direct interaction with the model and other team members. There's no computer software making limitations and suggesting shortcuts. Of course some concept drawings exist as the basis, but the final geometric forms are sculpted to wax (it can be inserted, too, if needed)

When artists have finally created the model, engineers scan it and find a way to build it. Of course some drawings are needed, but the geometry information is 3D as soon as the artists create it.

Comment: They dont actually go directly from scan to model. But these clay models are quite rare and far between nowdays. Only a handful of designers know how to make stuff out of clay. Clay has lots of limitations of its own

Comment: @joojaa surely there's some iteration process where the geometry evolves in a computer, too. I believe remarkable manufacturing cost cuts and technicaI advantages can be achieved by modifications which cause minor changes to the visible surface. I believe in some phase creative artists are kicked out of the production preparing process and can start to do something else. These beliefs are based on television programs, not on being in a design team or even at hearing distance.

Comment: Industrial designers are actually closer to engineers than artists. But to be honest i dont really know if big companies still use clay models. I asked one vw designer and he claimed its all digital, and the only car ive been involved in was also all digital.

Comment: @joojaa One former primary master chief designer of Volkswagen https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-H06734,_Grundsteinlegung_f%C3%BCr_Werk_des_KdF-Wagens.jpg got overdose of clay in years 1914-1918 and that can still affect how the company works today.

Comment: @joojaa videos like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srJjd5t4Wtk suggest that people who can transform concept drawings to a perfectly fitting 3D model in presented way, could also do the same with real clay. Do industrial designers perform the transformation something differently with their computers (= in somehow less demanding way)?

Comment: Yes its much less demanding to do this on a computer, more importantly takes less time. Yes, you can go directly from concept drawing to model or projection puctures easily. But you can not jump directly to the projection drawings without having a 3D to verify that it indeed is possible.

Comment: More importantly it eliminates 2 very work intensive stages and results in a more flexible model. More iterations, less errors and simultaneus modifications and easier reflection control. But yeah physical models are great for tactile surfaces.